# Webdav stops working after a few seconds

Tags: 13.04, webdav

With Ubuntu 13.10, I connect to two different OwnCloud installations and can browse for only a few seconds before it freezes the connection and stops working. When I try to reinstate the connection it fails to even ask for the password (Ubuntu was told to forget the password). I did check the webdav connection through Firefox on two computers and ES File Explorer on android. I know that this isn't a webdav problem and don't know what is happening in Ubuntu to stop being able to read the connection.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in ubuntu 13.10.
Still no fix. 
See here :
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1223356

The problem seems to be with gvfs-dav (a component of Nautilus = Ubuntu's file manager),
so until it is fixed, if ever, you can use a different file manager that does not rely on gvfs, like **Krusader**, in which dav shares work fine. 
See: http://www.krusader.org/